# How to implement HMTX with Django Class Based Views

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, htmx

I am trying to understand how to utilise htmx with Django Class Based Views. To provide some context, here is a reflection of the scenario in which I want to implement django class based views and htmx together:

I have an initial view, which renders the main template and initial context. As part of this initial context, I am including a date form. I want to use htmx to post the data from this form to an APIView (let’s call it APIView1).

I would like APIView1 to ingest the data which is posted to it via htmx, run a function on it, and then return data back as context, while rendering a partial template (let’s call it PartialTemplate1) which utilises that context. So from what I understand, I can do this within a get() function; so it may look a little like this:

views.py

```py
Class InitialView(View):
    template_name = “initial_template.html”
    form_class = date_form
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    …
    date_form=self.form_class()
    context = {
        'date_form': date_form
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)

Class APIView1(APIView):
    template_name = “PartialTemplate1.html”
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        date = request.POST.get(‘date’)
        timeslots = function(date)
        context = {
            ‘timeslots’: timeslots
        }
        return render(request, template_name, context).
```

initial_template.html:

```html
<form hx-post='{% url "appname:apiview1_url" %}' hx-target='#ticket-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ date_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="View Time Slots">
</form>
<div id="booking-form-container">
    <div id="ticket-form">
         <input type="submit" value="View Time Slots">
    </div>
</div>
```

PartialTemplate1.html:

```html
<div class="container mt-5" style="width: 80%">
    <div id="time-slots">
        {% for timeslot in timeslots %}
            <button name="timeslot_button" hx-post='{% url " appname:apiview2_url" %}' hx-target="#booking-form-container" hx-swap="outerHTML show:#ticket-form:top " hx-include="this">
            {{ timeslot.start_time|format_time }} - {{ timeslot.end_time|format_time }}
            <input name="data-timeslot" value="{{timeslot}}" type="hidden">
            </button>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

PartialTemplate1 should be rendered within the main template, upon submission of the date form. This should include a list of available time slots on the given date.

The user is then able to select a time slot from the PartialTemplate1 segment. When they select a time slot, the data of which time slot they have selected, should then be posted to another APIView (APIView2):

```py
Class APIView2(APIView):
    form_class = ticket_form
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    selected_timeslot = request.POST.get(‘timeslot’)
        timeslot_ticket_data = function(selected_timeslot)
        form = self.form_class(timeslot_ticket_data=timeslot_ticket_data)
    return response(form)
```

The APIView2 would replace what was the list of time slots with the form instance (ticket_form). The user could then complete the form.

Now, from what I understand, the data from both the date form, which was initially included, the timeslot selected, and the tickets they would select on the ticket form, should all be available in that initial template? So going back to my initial view, I should be able to, in the post request, get all of this data that I have generated using htmx and my APIViews, and post it together (when submitting the ticket_form) to create, what would in this example be a booking summary?

```py
Class InitialView(View):
…
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        date = request.GET.get(‘date)
        timeslot = request.GET.get(‘timeslot’)
        form = ticket_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            *create a new model instance using above data on post*

        redirect(reverse(app_name:booking_summary, kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs[‘slug’]}))
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

From what you you need to achieve, you don't need three separate views. Just have two: `InitialView` and `TimeslotView`. `InitialView` should render the `date_form` during `GET` request and on `POST` request return `timeslots` partial template (partial_template_1.html). `TimeslotsView` will then only have to handle `POST` request and return `ticket_form`.

Here is the suggested structure:

```py
class DateView(View): # or InitialView
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = dict(date_form=date_form())
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        date = request.POST.get("date")
        timeslots = ....
        context = dict(timeslots=timeslots)
        return render(request, timeslots_partial.html, context)

class TimeslotsView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        timeslot = request.POST.get("timeslot")
        timeslot_data = function(timeslot)
        ticket_form = ticket_form(timeslot_data=timeslot_data)
        context = dict(form=ticket_form)
        return render(request, ticket_form_partial.html, context)

class TicketView(View):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       ....
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       ....
```

**The main template**:

```html
<form hx-post='{% url "appname:date_view" %}' hx-target='#ticket-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ date_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="View Time Slots">
</form>
<div id="booking-form-container">
    <div id="ticket-form">
         <!-- leave this empty  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**timeslots_partial.html**

I turned timeslots into a form because I believe it's only logical to submit it as a form rather an abitrary value (there are exceptions I guess but I don't see them in this case.

```html
<form hx-post='{% url "appname:timeslots_view" %}' hx-target='#ticket-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="timeslot">Available timeslots </label>
    <select id="timeslot" name="timeslot">
    {% for timeslot in timeslots %}
      <option value="{{timeslot}}"> {{ timeslot.start_time|format_time }} - {{ timeslot.end_time|format_time }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="View ticket">
</form>
<div id="booking-form-container">
    <div id="ticket-form">
         <input type="submit" value="View Time Slots">
    </div>
</div>
```

**ticket_form.html**

```html
<form hx-post='{% url "appname:ticket_view" %}' hx-swap="none">
   <!-- I don't know what you want to do after submitting a ticket, maybe redirect?? -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ ticket_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save ticket">
</form>
```

**NOTE**
In your `get` methods in both APIViews, you are trying to access the submitted value by `request.POST.get(..)`. This can't work. `request.POST` will always be  `None` when used inside a method that's not `post`. Same as you use `request.GET.get(...)` inside a method that's not `get`, it will be `None`. So remember to use respective to get values from the request object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what if I had more data I wanted to accumulate, i.e. there were more than 2 functions I wanted to run. So similar example but with more views? Would I still be able to feed this data back to the initial view and post it?

Comment: As long as whatever data you generate gets passed to the context, you should be able to get it to render.